# Creating array of pointers using input from stdin

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I understand how to create it in general. For example:

```
int ar1[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int ar2[4] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
int* ar[2] = {ar1, ar2};
cout << *(ar[1]+2);
```

will output:

```
6
```

Now, I would like to create the same array using `cin`. The format of the input is the following. The first line stores the number of arrays `n`. The other `n` lines store first the number of elements in the array, and then the elements of the arrays. For example:

```
2
3 1 2 3
4 4 5 6 7
```

To parse the input and create the array I have the following code:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
cout << "The number of variable-length arrays: " << n << endl;

int* ar [n];

for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
    cout << "..reading the array number: " << k + 1 << endl;
    int n_el; cin >> n_el;
    cout << "The array contains " << n_el << " elements." << endl;
    int ar_k [n_el];

    for (int j = 0; j < n_el; j++) {
        cin >> ar_k[j] ;
    }

    ar[k] = ar_k;

    for (int j = 0; j < n_el; j++) {
        cout << *(ar[k] + j) << endl;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
The number of variable-length arrays: 2
..reading the array number: 1
The array contains 3 elements.
1
2
3
..reading the array number: 2
The array contains 4 elements.
4
5
6
7
```

However, if I try to access the arrays outside the loop, it does not work. Given the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    cout << *(ar[0] + j) << endl;
}
```

the output is:

```
4
32766
44613906
```

I guess it happens because as soon as you are out of the loop, the memory where the arrays are stored gets freed. How to prevent this? Or should I use a different approach to solve the task?

Comment: `cin` doesn't dynamically create arrays of pointers.   Also, `int* ar [n];` (where `n` is a variable) is invalid C++  - it is an extension supported by some compilers but not all.    Try using a standard container of some form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the memory is getting freed when you exit the loop.

Also your code is illegal `int* ar [n];` where n is a variable is *not* legal C++. Even though your compiler accepts it (another compiler would not).

One other approach is to use dynamic memory allocation using `new`. Replace

```
int* ar [n];
```

with

```
int** ar = new int*[n];
```

and

```
int ar_k [n_el];
```

with

```
int* ar_k = new int[n_el];
```

The point of dynamic allocation is that the memory doesn't get freed until you `delete` it.

Dynamic memory allocation is a big topic, and this answer just scratches the surface. Time for some reading.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just to clarify why it is illegal? `n` is fixed as soon as its value is initialised. Or it is fixed only when it is hardcoded?

Comment: C++ requires that `n` be a constant. That is something the compiler knows the value of before the program runs. Obviously that cannot be a value entered by the user. The rules of C are different, and your code would be legal C.

Comment: Good, thank you a lot! It is clear what should I read next :)